# Cython - 'Abstract declarator' compiler warning

Tags: python, c++, cython

The situation is as follows: I want to wrap the method Unit.getDistance

```
//Unit.h
class Unit{
    ....
    int getDistance(PositionOrUnit target) const;
};
//PositionUnit.h
class PositionOrUnit{
    PositionOrUnit(Unit unit = nullptr);
    PositionOrUnit(Position pos);
};
```

The library uses converting constructors to allow `Unit` or `Position` to be automatically constructed into a `PositionOrUnit` object by the compiler, so that it is possible to pass a `Unit` or `Position` object directly into this method.

```
#cUnit.pxd
ctypedef UnitInterface *Unit
cdef cppclass UnitInterface:
    int getDistance(PositionOrUnit target) const

#cPositionUnit.pxd
cdef cppclass PositionOrUnit:
    PositionOrUnit() #fake for nullptr unit
    PositionOrUnit(Unit unit)
    PositionOrUnit(Position pos)
```

Now I don't know how to make a converting constructor in Python, so I use subclass polymorphism to get this to work. I declare a base class `PositionUnitConverter` and have `Unit` and `Position` subclass from it.

```
#PositionUnit.pyx

cdef class PositionUnitConverter:
    cdef cPositionUnit.PositionOrUnit getPositionOrUnit(self):
        return cPositionUnit.PositionOrUnit()

cdef class PositionOrUnit(PositionUnitConverter):
    cdef cPositionUnit.PositionOrUnit thisobj

    cdef cPositionUnit.PositionOrUnit getPositionOrUnit(self):
        return self.thisobj

#Unit.pyx

cdef class Unit(PositionUnitConverter):
    cdef cUnit.Unit thisptr

    cdef cPositionUnit.PositionOrUnit getPositionOrUnit(self):
        return cPositionUnit.PositionOrUnit(self.thisptr)

    def getDistance(self, PositionUnitConverter target):
        return self.thisptr.getDistance(target.getPositionOrUnit())
```

The end result is that in my Python code I can call Unit.getDistance with either type of object still.

```
# this works
unit.getDistance(unit2)
```

But now I get several of these warnings:

```
CyBW\CyBW.cpp(15698) : warning C4190: 'abstract declarator' has C-linkage specified, but 
returns UDT 'BWAPI::PositionOrUnit' which is incompatible with C  
../include/BWAPI/PositionUnit.h(13) : see declaration of 'BWAPI::PositionOrUnit'
```

The .cpp code generated at that line is: (split to be easier to read)

```
__pyx_vtable_4CyBW_5BWAPI_PositionUnitConverter.getPositionOrUnit = (BWAPI::PositionOrUnit 
(*)(struct __pyx_obj_4CyBW_5BWAPI_PositionUnitConverter *)) 
__pyx_f_4CyBW_5BWAPI_21PositionUnitConverter_getPositionOrUnit;
```

My Questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong to get this warning
2. How can I avoid this warning?
3. or should I ignore this warning, and how?

If there is anything else I can provide to help, please comment.